# LDAP: Unknown error (0x8000500c) on server, locally working

Tags: iis, deployment, active-directory

I have this class [LDAP](http://pastebin.com/R9c4tg3U) which gets users from AD. It works locally, but when I deploy on a remote server I get Unknown error (0x8000500c).
As from stack trace on remote machine I presume that error is thrown while invoking GetUsers() library method:

```
[COMException (0x8000500c): Unknown error (0x8000500c)]
Library.LDAP..ctor(String login) in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XXXLib\XXXLibrary\LDAP.cs:75
XXXLibrary.LDAP.<GetUsers>b__0(String login) in C:\Users\adkozak\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XXXLib\XXXLibrary\LDAP.cs:148
System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +110
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
XXXLibrary.LDAP.GetUsers(List`1 logins) in C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\XXXLib\XXXLibrary\LDAP.cs:148
```

Authentication on Remote IIS is set to:

`Windows Authentication: Enabled`

`ASP.NET Impersonation: Enabled`

Rest of types are disabled.

Every clue, help would be appreciated. I have no idea what I could do wrong.

Comment: in 2023, experiencing this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I've finally found what was wrong - Error 0x8000500c means `Active Directory Datatype Cannot be Converted to/from a Native DS Datatype` I've looked into LDAP entry using [BeaverTail ADSI Browser](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html) and noticed that one of properties is not string but array. Hope that this helps anyone!